# Emacs Re-Indent File

Tags: emacs, prolog, lisp, auto-indent

[image]I have two files one .pl .lisp
I have written them using the emacs editor inside SWi and Lispwork, while I was coding I have set auto-fill-mode and used the editor in the default mode.

I would like to reindent all the code in emacs "style", is there a way to indent again all the code, be sure that all code is (under 80 columns auto-fill-mode), and make the code on less line as possible?

I have tried select-all + alt-x + indent-region or ctrl+alt+
But it seems that some line of code are indented in a strange way, is there a way to be sure thet the code is indented in the proper way?

Comment: Can you give us an example of how it was indented `strangely`? lisp and prolog indentation is pretty standard.

Comment: In free-form languages, Emacs does it pretty easily, as @rajashekar pointed out. In other languages where indentation can change semantics, Emacs cannot judge sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for answering some code il like the image I have uploded in the question